# MvvmCross Community Plugin for Sqlite with Unified API

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I've recently taken a client with an existing app using MvvmCross and the Community.Plugins.Sqlite.  It looks like the old 3.1.1 version is all that is in nuget, which supports the classic ios api.  Is there a version anywhere for the unified api?

Wally

Comment: I am hearing that there is no nuget component due to the recommendation to use Sqlite-NET api.  That's cool.  I've gone ahead and recompiled the source for the xamarin unified api.  fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

The Community code supports iOS unified but you have to download the latest source and compile.  We are debating whether or not to just swap out Sqlite-net for one of the PCL options.